# How do i copy data from closed files if file name and sheet name is given Using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA. In sheet 1 the file name and sheet name is given (these files are in  folder) from that file name name and sheet name wants to copy data of that file to  sheet 1. I wants to open first file and get that file from folder and paste all columns to sheet 1 in "User Column name"
i have tried but not getting exact output....Please help me

[image: Data in Sheet 1]
[image: SystemConfiguration]
[image: Expecting output]
Code:

```
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    'DECLARE AND SET VARIABLES
    Dim wbk As Workbook
    Dim Filename As String
    Dim Path As String
    Dim mainwb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
     Dim search_result As Range   'range search result
        Dim blank_cell As Long
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim rowCount As Long
     Dim add As Range
     Workbooks("abc.xlsm").Activate
       Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
        wb.Sheets("Sheet 1").Activate
        LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        LastColumn = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Columns.Count).End(xlUp).Column
    For i = 2 To LastRow
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Select
        Filename1 = Selection.Value
        Sheetname1 = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
           Workbooks("abc.xlsm").Activate
        input_directory = Sheets("SystemConfiguration").Range("B2").Value & "\"
         Filename = Dir(input_directory & "*.xls")
        Workbooks("abc.xlsm").Activate
        'Do While Len(Filename) > 0  'IF NEXT FILE EXISTS THEN
        Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(input_directory & Filename)
         Set wbk = ActiveWorkbook
         variable = ActiveSheet.Name
         If variable = Sheetname1 & Filename = Filename1 Then
           GoTo PROC
       End If
         ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows(1).Copy
         Workbooks("abc.xlsm").Activate
        'ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
         Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
          Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")
        For Each cell In ws.Columns(3).Cells
            If IsEmpty(cell) = True Then cell.Select: Exit For
        Next cell
     Set add = Selection
     Selection.Offset(0, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
     rowCount = Selection.Rows.Count
     Range(add, add.Offset(rowCount - 1, 0)).Value = Filename
     Range(add.Offset(0, 1), add.Offset(rowCount - 1, 1)).Value = variable
         wbk.Close savechanges:=False
         Filename = Dir
    'Loop
    PROC:
     Next i
    End Sub
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You've used `Filename  = Dir(input_directory & "*.xls")`, do you want to exclude the `.xlsx` ?

Comment: it should read all xlsx , xlsm files

Comment: You have an error in your code: you must change `LastColumn = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Columns.Count).End(xlUp).Column` to 
`LastColumn = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column` to get the last column number

Comment: made changes but not getting exact output

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer...!!!!!!!

```
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim wbk As Workbook
    Dim Filename As String
    Dim Path As String
    Dim mainwb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim FileThere As String
    Dim rowCount As Long
     Dim add As Range
     Dim myFilePath As String
      Dim myWorkbook As Workbook
     Workbooks("aaa.xlsm").Activate
       Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
        wb.Sheets("Sheet10").Activate
        LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        LastColumn = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Columns.Count).End(xlUp).Column

    For i = 2 To LastRow
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Select
        Filename1 = Selection.Value
        Sheetname1 = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value


        Workbooks("aaa.xlsm").Activate

        myFilePath = Sheets("Sheet9").Range("B2").Value & "\" & Filename1
    mySheetname = Sheetname1

    If Dir(myFilePath, vbDirectory) <> vbNullString Then
      MsgBox "File  There!"
      Set myWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myFilePath)
    On Error Resume Next
         myWorkbook.Sheets(CStr(mySheetname)).Activate
    On Error GoTo 0


        ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows(1).Copy
         Workbooks("aaa.xlsm").Activate
        'ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
         Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
          Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet10")
        For Each cell In ws.Columns(3).Cells
            If IsEmpty(cell) = True Then cell.Select: Exit For
        Next cell
     Set add = Selection
     Selection.Offset(0, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
     rowCount = Selection.Rows.Count
     Range(add, add.Offset(rowCount - 1, 0)).Value = Filename1
     Range(add.Offset(0, 1), add.Offset(rowCount - 1, 1)).Value = Sheetname1
         myWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False

Else
     MsgBox "File Not There!"
End If

    Next i
    End Sub
```